# Is there a way to change auto-formatting in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, dart, format

It is really annoying, but whenever I alt tab in Android studio, there is change in the format of the code, and some other random changes, where {} move on their own and such. It is also different from dart format, so I don't know what is even going on.

[Before doing anything I have this i.e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8fHD.png)

[I now move the _letter = 'B'; code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx5wg.png)

[But it goes back to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueSAa.png)

I guess comments, do not allow me to put a picture in but this is my Dart Smart keys
[Nothing for Dart Smart Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rltC.png)

[Nothing really for code style in Dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQpQt.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Settings->Editor->General->Smart Keys and uncheck all formatting options for the language that you currently use (dart in your case).
[image: Uncheck the undesired options]

Comment: Couldn't add a picture to the comment, so I edited the post, but for Dart, I do not have anything I can change. This just randomly started to occur an hour or two ago, which really is confusing me, because I didn't really use any hotkey or installed new extensions.

Comment: I have no reason for this but I think is worth trying. Go to File->Invalidate cache and restart , and see if this behavior still persist.

Comment: That didn't work, so in the end, I just reset android studio, and it looks like this fixed it, but this is a very interesting change. Hopefully, this does not repeat, but maybe this will work later. I have had a really weird experience with android studio today, with it keep doing weird stuff, and some solutions only working after resetting android studio, or doing the same exact steps multiple times.